# Parse a tabbed tree text file and create a Treeview in Pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a text file containing a tabbed tree structure with the following format:

```
ROOT
    Node1
        Node2
            Node3
                Node4
    Node5
    Node6
```

I want to display this data using `pygtk` Treeview as follow :
[TreeView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0inZM.png)

I found this solution : https://gist.github.com/bussolon/4473921

How can I adapt the `print_tree()` function to build a `gtk` TreeStore ?